# Is there a tool to encrypt a file or directory?

Tags: software-recommendation, files, encryption, directory

What's the most popular way to encrypt individual files or folders?

Comment: Question is a bit unclear.  Do you want to manually encrypt and decrypt files, or on the fly?

Comment: Instead of 'most popular' , fitting a solution to your requirements might be helpful (as per psusi's question).   Are you looking for a combination of easy, reliable, native, secure, fast, open source?   All or some of these?

Comment: I'd like to add the remark that contrary to what some answers claim, TrueCrypt is [not considered Free Software or Open Source](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/TrueCrypt#Licensing) by Debian/Ubuntu/Fedora/Red Hat/Arch Linux/OpenSuse/Gentoo/etc.

Answer (score 48):

GnuPG (GPG) can use asymmetric and symmetric encryption. Asymmetric crypto involves a two keys, a public key for encryption and a private key for decryption. See [djeikyb answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/27806/6969) on this page for asymmetric key usage.

For symmetric encryption, the encryption and decryption keys are equal. It is important to realize that most people are very bad at choosing strong passwords. Thus, an encryption scheme using passwords should use a key-derivation function that takes more resources (time, memory) to slow down brute-force attacks.

For a description of GnuPG's KDF, see [this Crypto Stack Exchange post](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9985/kdf-and-number-of-iterations-for-gpg). Example usage of symmetric encryption:

```
gpg --symmetric < unencrypted_file > encrypted_file
```

Decryption:

```
gpg --decrypt < encrypted_file > decrypted_file
```

Note that `gpg` caches the symkey by default (documented behavior). In order to avoid that, use `--no-symkey-cache` option as described in a [related answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1093851/295286).

[Manual page of gpg](http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manpage.html).

---

*old answer for users who are able to chose good keys, see note below*

For single files, `openssl` is very useful, especially when sending the file over an unsecured channel (e.g. e-mail). It's free (in money and in freedom), unlike Truecrypt, which is only free in money.

**NOTE**: the password that you enter here will be processed by **one MD5** iteration <sup>1</sup>. If you chose a password "123456", then you will have very little security.

Encrypt:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -salt -in unencrypted_file -out encrypted_file
```

You'll be asked for a password, which you have to input twice.

Decrypt:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -in encrypted_file -out unencrypted_file
```

Manual page for the [enc](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/enc.html) program.

<sup>1</sup> `openssl enc` uses the digest function defined by the `-md` option (default md5) and invokes function [`EVP_BytesToKey()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_BytesToKey.html) with an iteration count of 1. This can be found in the openssl source at `apps/enc.c`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without a passpharse?

Comment: @Assaf Lavie: OpenSSL does not support keyfiles if you meant that, although it can read a password from the first line of a file. Read the manual page on [openssl, section Pass phrase arguments](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/openssl.1ssl.html#contenttoc4).

Comment: additionally you can use the "-a" flag which allows you to copy the crypted text, like so:
"openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -in unencrypted_file -out encrypted_file
"

Comment: @v2r To add for further readers: `-a` base64-encodes the input (alias of `-base64`), to decrypt it you also need to add the `-a` option.

Comment: Why do you use `aes-256-cbc` instead of `aes-256`? What is the difference?

Comment: @Lucio `aes-256` is an alias for `aes-256-cbc`, there is no difference. [CBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipher_block_chaining) is a mode of operation for block ciphers. See the manual page of [`enc(1)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/enc.html) for a list of supported ciphers.

Comment: @AssafLavie, Why would one encrypt a file without a passphrase?

Comment: @user1717828 Asymmetric crypto allows that, the encryption key can be made public while the decryption key is kept secret.

Comment: @Lekensteyn your examples seem to be for files, how about a directory? Or are the names you use `(un)encrypted_file` generic and then "_file" can be replaced with "_directory"?

Comment: Be advised that when you decrypt, the resulting files/folders (if sensitive) may need to be securely deleted after use. As far as I know there is no Linux app that can encrypt and decrypt in its own secure environment. This used to be so easy with Truecrypt now defunct. Maybe one day we will get an app in Linux that will do what IOS has been doing for years: encrypting/decrypting any of your files and folders on the fly -- without having to put them in a .Private folder etc

Comment: @elmclose If you write files to a `tmpfs` filesystem (usually `/tmp` qualifies as such, but check `mount | grep /tmp` just to be sure), then no trace will be left on the disk *if* you have no swap partition (check `free -m`). Of course, it may leak to other locations depending on the applications you open the files in. If you are looking for TrueCrypt functionality, search for Full Disk Encryption. On Linux this can be done with LUKS (cryptsetup).

Comment: That is fine @Lekensteyn if you are simply opening your encrypted data to view. If you launch an app to change anything the data leaks all over the disk. Also the user still has to do all the housekeeping work such as flushing out the tmpfs or rebooting the system. Full disk encryption is the only way but it slows down the disk and also over the top for most people. We simply do not have a use-and-forget tool in Linux at the moment.

Answer (score 31):

I use [Seahorse](http://live.gnome.org/Seahorse) for this. It's a Gnome front-end for GnuPG and integrates well with nautilus: [image: Nautilus integration]

To get nautilus integration, install the package `seahorse-nautilus` from the Software Center: [seahorse-nautilus](http://packages.ubuntu.com/seahorse-nautilus) [image: Install seahorse-nautilus]

Comment: this only works if you have a GPGs keys created in your system ...

Comment: @hhlp: djeikyb's answer explains how to do that.

Comment: I'm wanting to encrypt my GPG key.

Answer (score 19):

- EncFS system tray applet for GNOME [cryptkeeper](http://packages.ubuntu.com/cryptkeeper)

[TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/): **discontinued, [unsecure](http://truecrypt.sourceforge.net/)** source-available freeware Disk Encryption Software.

Comment: +1, encfs - with or without a GUI - is very useful and enough for most purposes.

Comment: Cryptkeeper is awesome - simple, powerful and a breeze to set up with Dropbox (http://askubuntu.com/questions/19613/how-can-i-do-individual-file-encryption-on-dropbox/19630#19630).

Comment: TrueCrypt is not packaged in Ubuntu (or any other major distributions) for licensing concerns.

Comment: Cryptkeeper works perfectly on Linux Mint 14

Comment: TrueCrypt is not that open-source. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truecrypt#Licensing_and_Open_Source_status

Comment: 'WARNING: Using TrueCrypt is not secure' - TrueCrypt

Comment: Links are expired...

Comment: wikipedia: "TrueCrypt is a discontinued source-available freeware utility"

Answer (score 17):

A cli method would be [GnuPG](http://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual.html), and maybe tar. This is a short guide for reference, you really should read the documentation.

First run `gpg --gen-key`. Follow the prompts to generate your public/private key pair. Now you can encrypt files: `gpg -e foo.txt`. This will create a file called `foo.txt.gpg`. GnuPG does not delete the original unencrypted file, it's up to you whether you want it hanging around. To decrypt foo.txt.gpg, run `gpg foo.txt.gpg`. Decrypting will prompt you before overwriting existing files.

If you need to encrypt a directory, tar it first:

```
tar -cf foo.tar foo/
gpg -e foo.tar
```

You can rename the encrypted file whatever you want. When decrypted, the original file name is preserved.

Comment: The advantages of this method are: First it does not require installation of additional packages; Second it does not require root access. I would add compression to the tar command (xz or gz).

Comment: Fwiw, a modern tool would be [age](https://github.com/FiloSottile/age). cf tptacek's ["the problem with pgp"](https://www.latacora.com/blog/2019/07/16/the-pgp-problem/). Haven't got time now for a proper amendment.

Answer (score 12):

There's also [eCryptfs](http://launchpad.net/ecryptfs), which Ubuntu uses to encrypt Home Directories.

You can select home directory encryption at installation, or you can setup a single directory, `$HOME/Private` by default, using the [ecryptfs-setup-private](http://manpg.es/ecryptfs-setup-private) utility.  This folder can be configured to automatically mount at login and unmount at logout.  Every single file and folder within `$HOME/Private`, recursively, will be encrypted.

Comment: Unfortunately eCryptfs is VERY slow. Also there are few bugs in latest version

Comment: On the contrary, if anything eCryptfs is faster than gpg; by default gpg attempts to compress before encrypting. And eCryptfs is now also used by most Android's

Answer (score 2):

You may also use "Academic Signature" to use elliptic curve cryptography with a wxWidgets GUI. It is open source but not in the repositories.
It mainly does ECC asymmetric encryption, signatures and timestamps. But the tool also has a Menu entry for invoking Gnupg(RSA) and direct access to symmetric en-/decryption of files offering AES and other algorithms.
Its homepage is here: https://www.academic-signature.org

I use it a lot for protecting files in transit and for digitally signing academic documents(transcripts, letters of recommendation, grade lists etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I've taken some of the other suggestions and created a simple shell script wrapper (for the lazy)

https://github.com/orionM/ssl-crypt-tools

enjoy

Comment: hmm, bash script using `openssl aes-256-cbc ...` You know instead of using `if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then... fi` you can just use `||`? And there are [some people who think OpenSSL](http://tinyurl.com/h4egm8s) "* has had several major security flaws in the last year [**Heartbleed**] while the Snowden documents show that GPG is one of the few programs that might stump the NSA when used properly. The OpenSSL code is also a complete cesspool and has terrible test coverage. (Disclosure: [he] work[s] on a "OpenSSL sucks; let's fix it" project.) – jbarlow*"