# What software is available for Folder Lock?

Tags: 11.10

What software is available for locking folder and files just like FolderLockxp software in windows?

Comment: Does that encrypt the folders? You could use TrueCrypt, or ecyptfs for that. If you just want to set the permissions, you can do that in Nautilus or Dolphin.

Comment: related question -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/27770/is-there-a-tool-to-encrypt-a-file-or-directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not really any software for "folder locking", but you can achieve this through permissions, and optionally access control lists (you have to enable this in fstab by adding "acl" to the list of mount options for your hard drive, and by installing eicel).

Using the standard unix permissions on your folders is a pretty simple but effective way to lock folders without software.

Comment: Locking a folder with a password sounds like encryption to me, just implemented in a user friendly way.