# Is there a way to encrypt my files without full disk encryption

Tags: security, encryption

I want to encrypt my files and folders without full disk encryption and encrypted volumes. Can anyone help me?

Comment: @NikTh this is not a duplicate of that question, I didn't want encrypted volumes like truecrypt

Comment: Here is a bunch of questions-answers about encryption/decryption of every kind. I'm pretty sure that this has been already answered.

Comment: oh, sorry. My mistake

Comment: I retracted my vote and I cannot vote now for closing. The first link I gave was wrong. Here is the [correct one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/27770/is-there-a-tool-to-encrypt-a-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [site](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/11/encryptdecrypt-files-from-nautilus.html) should give you all the information you need. The link was found at upubuntu.com. Here is a direct quote from the site:

> "encrypt or decrypt your files using the Nautilus context menu
>   (right-click menu) under Ubuntu"

1. Add a PGP key so that you can encrypt your files with it, by opening
   "Passwords and Keys", click the add button, select "PGP Key", then
   click Continue.
2. Add the seahorse-nautilus plugin with

> sudo apt-get install
>       seahorse-nautilus && nautilus -q && nautilus
>
> Right click to pick any file and then select Encrypt  In a pop-up,
>   pick your key, set "Sign message as: Your key" and click OK. Another
>   pop-up asks for the passphrase which matches up w/ the PGP key.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/help/referencing

Comment: @NikTh Thanks for the link, that helped. I will make sure to do that next time.

Comment: Please at least include (you can quote) something from this link that answers the question. A simple link is not considered as an answer at all. It is just a link.

Comment: I think I should bookmark that for later