# How does one set up a encrypted file?

Tags: encryption

I would like to learn how to set up a encrypted folder or file on my computer.  I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit.

Comment: P.S.  I do not have a "smart phone", just the computer.

Comment: Have you tried Truecrypt???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a tool to encrypt a file or directory?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/27770/is-there-a-tool-to-encrypt-a-file-or-directory)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to encrypt individual folders?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/104542/how-to-encrypt-individual-folders)

Answer (score 0):

E.G. via `encfs`

- Install `encfs`

  ```
  sudo apt-get install encfs
  ```
- Create a folder for the encrypted files

  ```
  mkdir -p ~/encrypted
  ```
- Create a folder for the decrypted files

  ```
  mkdir -p ~/decrypted
  ```
- Start

  ```
  encfs ~/encrypted ~/decrypted
  ```

  And use e.g. the <kbd>pre-configured paranoia mode</kbd>
- Check

  ```
  mount | grep decrypted
  ```

  Sample output

  ```
  encfs on /home/aboettger/decrypted type fuse.encfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000,default_permissions)
  ```
- Place some files in `~/decrypted`

  ```
  touch ~/decrypted/foo
  ```

  and check the content of `~/encrypted`

  ```
  ls ~/encrypted
  ```

  Sample output

  ```
  guV8sPH68cUeEsZoNAsNBBCC
  ```

---

- Use the *Gnome Encfs Manager* to manage your encrypted folders

  ```
  sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gencfsm/ppa
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install gnome-encfs-manager
  ```
- Start via Dash/GNOME Shell

  <kbd>Gnome Encfs Manager</kbd>

  and add and configure your folder